# Get list bullets to border of container while keeping line indents?

Tags: html, css, layout, html-lists, margin

In my website I have a list within my content. I don't like the standard indent of HTML lists, however so far I was only able to find two ways of dealing with the indents.

**Option 1:**
This will get the list bullets to the very border of the containing element. However, the line indent for longer list items doesn't match for longer entries.

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 10%;
  background: black;
}

.container {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10%;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
 
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="container">
     <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>
          item with very very very very very very very very very very very very very 
          very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very 
          long text.
        </li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Option 2:**
This is actually the standard HTML layout. My line indents are nice and tidy, however my bullet points are not at the border of the container. I could now remove the padding of the `ul` element, but then the bullet points will stick out of the container. Although, I could fiddle around with the padding, until they match option 1, what if I change the font-size later or make other changes?

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 10%;
  background: black;
}

.container {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10%;
}

ul {
  list-style-position: outside;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="container">
     <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>
          item with very very very very very very very very very very very very very 
          very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very 
          long text.
        </li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Question:** Is there a way to combine the positioning of the bullet points in Option 1 with the line indent of Option 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that by just adding some left margin on your list like so, here I use `em` units for the left margin so the margin scales correctly with the `font-size` of the list:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="container">
     <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>
          item with very very very very very very very very very very very very very 
          very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very 
          long text.
        </li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but isn't that more or less the same effect as changing the value for padding? What I mean by that, is that it is a fixed value, not a relative positioning to the div border.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The list is inside the div. The 16px left offset is applied _relative to the div_. So the list is indeed relatively positioned to the div border.

Comment: The list yes, but not the bullet points. To illustrate what I mean, change the font-size of the ul in your snippet to something bigger, like 27px. The bullet points will stick out.

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide a solution that scales with variable font sizes, please take another look.